# Sum columns with similar value- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sum all fields that have similar value.

I have a simple SQL query that give me back this result:

[image]

For example, the name like 'Climatizzazione' has to be sum to 'Climatizzatori Samsung' and 'Climatizzatori Daiki' and get a unique result.

The final result would be like that:

```
| name | totale_fatturato |

| -------- | -------------- |

| Climatizzazione | 535.241,583465|

| Scaldabagni| 90680,77684|

| Differenziali e Magnetotermici| 78511,185704|
```

ecc.......

This is my SQL query:

```
    SELECT 
cl.name, 
 SUM(od.total_price_tax_excl) AS totale_fatturato
FROM `ww_ps_order_detail` AS `od`
INNER JOIN `ww_ps_product` AS p ON od.product_id = p.id_product
INNER JOIN `ww_ps_category_lang` AS cl ON p.id_category_default = cl.id_category
WHERE od.ID_ORDER IN (
SELECT ID_ORDER
FROM ww_ps_orders
WHERE 1=1 AND DATE_ADD >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND cl.id_lang = 1
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY totale_fatturato DESC
LIMIT 10
```

What i have to do for get the result i want? Thx!

Comment: what's the logic for the renaming ? there could be several cases which might sound similar

Comment: is this the only case happening with `Climatizzazione` ? or do you have similar cases with other words ?

Comment: Because in the DB the categorys of products doesn't did well, so when is suppose to be all in one category "Climatizzazione", i have multiple cateogory that is suppose to be together ("Climatizzazione","Climatizzazione Samsung", ecc). Normally this problem there is only with this category

Comment: i edit the question adding the ID's of list

Comment: Maybe you could try GROUP BY SOUNDEX(name). But this will do only when the names are really similar. Or you could try to use LIKE if they all begin with the same string. If the names are not similar enough, I think you won't find a proper solution for that.

Comment: @trillion no, because i have other situations to handle with this structure of query so the ideal is to find a solution without changing the query.

JonasMetzler soundex not working. What do u propose with using like?

Comment: i would then suggest to manually create a mapping where you have those cases and then use the new renamed column

Comment: If all names that have to be grouped together start with the same string, use name LIKE 'yourstring%', if they all end with the same string, use name LIKE '%yourstring'. If they all sound very similar, SOUNDEX can be used. If none of this works, I guess you should rename them or add a further column like "nameGroup" to mark names that belong to the same group. Then you will fill this new column as you want and group by this column in your query.

Comment: You must create a criteria of similarity. The criteria which is value-independent. I.e. you give two values and this criteria to somebody, and he unambiguously tells does these values are similar or not. Without such criteria you cannot solve your task deterministically. Simple example of such criteria: the most 1st words of two values are equal.

Comment: @Akina can i use the id of these category?

Comment: ?? Look at your data - id_category for the rows which you want to be grouped differs.

Comment: Based on your data - you may try `GROUP BY (LEFT(name, 10))`, for example.

Comment: That's look fine! @Akina

Comment: But I recommend you to create "similarity table" which contains the pairs (actual name - canonical name), join it by actual name and group by canonical name.

Comment: Or even combine SOUNDEX with LIKE or LEFT. As already mentioned, this is all risky and can be avoided by adding a further column like "nameGroup" to your table and then group by this column. Or a mapping table. You can fill column or table based on your condition.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I posted the solution that you have suggest to me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Akina, Jonas Metzler and Trillion, i found my solution.

So, how you have suggest me, i create a supplementary column with some cases where i can handle all the exceptions and group by this column.

This is my result:

```
    SELECT 
cl.name AS NAME, 
SUM(od.total_price_tax_excl) AS `totale_fatturato`,
CASE 
    WHEN cl.name LIKE 'Climatizza%' THEN 'Climatizzazione' 
    /* SOME OTHER CASES */
    ELSE cl.name
END  AS groupName
FROM `ww_ps_order_detail` AS `od`
INNER JOIN `ww_ps_product` AS p ON od.product_id = p.id_product
INNER JOIN `ww_ps_category_lang` AS cl ON p.id_category_default = cl.id_category
WHERE od.ID_ORDER IN (
SELECT ID_ORDER
FROM ww_ps_orders
WHERE 1=1 AND DATE_ADD >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND cl.id_lang = 1
GROUP BY groupName
ORDER BY totale_fatturato DESC
```

Comment: Well, the idea of using a further column or even a mapping table was to really create it in the DB and use it in future instead of just use it within your query. But good to know you found your way.